# High level prototype functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, prototype, wrapper

I'm trying to create a wrapper in nodejs that abstracts different functions depending on the input of the main wrapper. So for example, lets say I have two different files, one called `usa` and one called `uk` and they both have the same functions, but they have different functionalities. I'm trying to have write a function, that given either the string `us` or `uk`, I get a wrapper function that I can call like this:

```
const Wrapper = MyWrapper('uk')
const func1Output = Wrapper.func1(10)
```

I currently have the above working, the `uk` file just defines the functions inside it as prototypes as follows:

```
function MyWrapper () { }
MyWrapper.prototype.func1 =  (input) => console.log(input)
return new MyWrapper()
```

This is working fine. My current situation is that there are lots of functions across different files that should be accessible by the wrapper. Its not just `func` and whatever else is in that specific file. This is my folder structure

```
wrappers
 - feed
  -- uk
  -- us
 - news
  -- uk
  -- us

//etc
```

Where each file titled `uk`/`us` has the prototype functions like in the second code snippet. So whenever I want to use the `feed` module for example, I have to do like in the first code snippet. So its a per-module prototype, its not high level where it would be per string (ie uk/us).

What I'm trying to do is have just one file, `index.js` in my wrappers folder which is responsible for giving me one wrapper for all of the modules. Something like `MyWrapper('uk').feed.func1()`

This is kind of a hard question to explain but I'd be happy to edit the post for more clarification if needed.

Comment: You may find proxies helpful for these situations.Take a look at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just return regular objects ?

```
 // wrapper/index.js
 const wrappers = {
  uk: {
   func1() { /*...*/ }
  },

  us: {
   func1() { /*...*/ }
  }
};

module.exports = country => wrappers[country];
```

That can be used as:

```
  const wrapper = require("./wrapper/")("uk");
 wrapper.func1();
```

Comment: I was so occupied trying to think of a complicated solution, I didn't even consider the simplest one.